# Django template parsing

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm creating an object in my view (with the help of [another site](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/02/22/django-patterns-part-4-forwards-generic-relations/)):

```
def myfavorites(request):

    queryset = Favorite.objects.favorites_for_user(user=request.user).select_related('content_type', 'content_object')

    generics = {}
    for item in queryset:
        generics.setdefault(item.content_type_id, set()).add(item.object_id)

        content_types = ContentType.objects.in_bulk(generics.keys())

        relations = {}
        for ct, fk_list in generics.items():
            ct_model = content_types[ct].model_class()
            relations[ct] = ct_model.objects.in_bulk(list(fk_list))

        for item in queryset:
            setattr(item, '_content_object_cache', 
                relations[item.content_type.id][item.object_id])

        return render_to_response('myfavorites.html', {
            'favorites':relations
        },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This passes an object to my template that reads:

```
{8L: {33L: <Author: Poe>}, 21L: {32L: <Book: The Great Gatsby>, 7L: <Book: Great Expectations>}, 22L: {7L: <Quote: Hamlet>}}
```

Where 8 is the id of my Author table, 21, is the id of my Book table, and 22 is the id of my Quote table.

I'm trying to list the object such that it reads:

> **Authors**
>   Poe
>
> **Books**
>   The Great Gatsby
>   Great Expectations
>
> **Quote**
>   Hamlet

How would I parse this object in the django template?

Comment: Can you transform the object in the view, or does this have to be a pure templates solution?

Comment: edited to show original view.  Any assistance with transforming the view?

Comment: At the bottom of my response, it says you should be able to parse the object (relations) in the view and split those to send to the template. This could be done in the render_to_response call like: `return render_to_response('myfavorites.html', {
            'authors':relations[8], 'books':relations[21], 'quotes': relations[22]
        },` You'd have to verify that you can use 8 for the 8L, you may need to convert to 8L 21L and 22L somehow in the relations[8/21/22] part of the return.

Answer (score 0):

I'd pass a context that is structured more like the following:

```
{
    'authors': [<Author: Poe>],
    'books': [
        <Book: The Great Gatsby>,
        <Book: Great Expectations>,
    ],
    'quotes': [<Quote: Hamlet>],
}
```

Then, you could easily do something like this:

```
<h1>Authors</h1>
{% for author in authors %}{{ author }}{% endfor %}

<h1>Books</h1>
{% for book in books %}{{ book }}{% endfor %}

<h1>Quotes</h1>
{% for quote in quotes %}{{ quote }}{% endfor %}
```

Comment: edited question to show original view.  Any assistance with transforming the view?

Answer (score 0):

Send the dictionaries to the template separately. Send one Authors dictionary, a Books dictionary, and a Quotes dictionary. Then you can parse each individually. Replace the following fields `a.name` with the name field of the author model, `b.name` with the name field of the book, and `q.quote` with the string field of the quote. Like so:

```
<div class="title">Authors</div>
{% for a in Authors %}
    <div>{{ a.name }}</div>
{% endfor %}

<div class="title">Books</div>
{% for b in Bookss %}
    <div>{{ b.name }}</div>
{% endfor %}

<div class="title">Quotes</div>
{% for q in Quotes %}
    <div>{{ q.quote }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

If you don't have control of the individual data, you can parse the object in the view to pass to the template:

```
Authors = object['8L'] # Not positive about the Long, may need to convert.
Books = object['21L'] # Not positive about the Long, may need to convert.
Quotes = object['22L'] # Not positive about the Long, may need to convert.
```

Return those variables to the template.

Comment: edited my question to show original view.  Priority is on not hitting the database 3 times, once for each table.  Any assistance with transforming the view?

Comment: Are you sure you're hitting the database only once as it is?  `content_type`s are usually heterogeneous and spread across multiple tables;  it's quite normal to see a select for each type represented in the query.  What's the resulting SQL in the query log?

Comment: You're right, it's not doing what I thought it was.  Any suggestion on how to limit the number of SQL queries?